# What do we know about the structure of $J_{0}(N)$ over $\mathbb{Q}[{\mu}_{{p}^{\infty}},{{k}}^{\frac{{1}}{{p}^{n}}}])$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

What is known about the structure of $J_{0}(N)$ over $\mathbb{Q}[\mu_{p^{\infty}}]$?

More generally, what do we know about $J_{0}(N)$ over 
$\mathbb{Q}[\mu_{p^{\infty}},k^{1/p^{n}}]$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Does it have infinite rank? Does it have finite torsion?

I am especially interested in the case where $N$ is the conductor of an elliptic curve with additive reduction over $\mathbb{Q}$ at $p$. (This curve acquires, of course, a Néron model with semistable reduction st $p$ over $\mathbb{Q}[\mu_{p^{\infty}}]$.)

EDIT:
In view of the previous comments, I would like to ask whether the $rank({J}_{0}(N))$ is still finite over
$$K(k)\colon=\lim_{\stackrel{\rightarrow}{n}}(\mathbb{Q}[{\mu}_{{p}^{\infty}},{{k}}^{{\frac{{1}}{{{p}^{n}}}}}])$$

Comment: Much is known over $\mathbf{Q}(\mu_{p^\infty})$. That the torsion is finite follows from work of Serre in the 1970s. It is also true that the rank is finite, but this is a very much deeper result (due to Kato in 2004).

Comment: Adding to David Loeffler's comment: I do not know about the case of additive reduction at p for the the latter (which I believe is open), but for an elliptic curve E having good ordinary reduction at p, you might also find some relevant theorems in Darmon-Tian, "Heegner points over towers of Kummer extensions", Canad. J. Math. 62, No. 5 (2010) 1060-1082 (at least when k is p-power free). See Proposition 1.4 (assuming B+S-D), Theorem 1.8, or Theorem 1.9 for instance. Roughly, the arithmetic of E here exhibits similar behaviour to that of E in the Z_p^2 extension of an imaginary quadratic field.

Comment: @jvo Can't we easily arrange that k is p-power-free WLOG? Did you maybe mean "when k is coprime to p"?

Comment: @David Loeffler Yes, WLOG! Thanks for pointing this out, I was writing in haste without thinking.

Comment: $X_0(49)$ has additive, but potentially good, reduction at $7$, and doesn't acquire a good reduction Neron model over $\mathbb Q(\mu_{7^{\infty}}).$

Comment: DavidLoeffler, @jvo: Thank you both for your helpful comments.
David: Can you tell me to which paper of Kato's you refer? (Maybe send me a link?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theorem 14.4 of Kato's paper in Asterisque 295 (2004), on page 236, says:

> Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $\mathbf{Q}$ such that there is a surjective homomorphism $J_1(N) \to A$ for some integer $N$. Then for any $m \ge 1$, $\bigcup_n A(\mathbf{Q}(\mu_{m^n}))$ is a finitely-generated abelian group.

(I'll leave the case of Kummer extensions to others, but this answers the question in the title.)

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the title now. Will accept your answer as soon as someone answers the Kummer case.

Answer (score 3):

The case of Kummer extensions is not yet completely understood, though partial results are obtained by Darmon-Tian in "Heegner points over towers of Kummer Extensions", Canad. J. Math. 62 (5) 2010, 1060 - 1080, following conjectures made in Dokchitser-Dokchitser "Computations in non-commutative Iwasawa theory," Proc. London Math. Soc. 94 (1) 2007, 211-272 (for instance). The results here are a bit tricky to summarize succinctly: There is a "root number dichotomy" which amounts to characterizing the forced vanishing of central values by the functional equation, and this must be considered a priori. The settings of forced vanishing typically correspond to Heegner-like growth of Mordell-Weil rank, as in the setting of anticyclotomic extensions, and this is described nicely in Darmon-Tian (who study a variation coming from varying parametrizations by Shimura curves). Anyhow, one predicts systematic growth of rank in these settings, and boundedness of rank in the others (i.e. when there is not forced vanishing coming from the functional equation). Also, results in this direction (including Kato + Rohrlich) are typically shown by combining some kind of analytic nonvanishing results for central values (such as Rohrlich's "On L-functions of elliptic curves in cyclotomic towers", Inventiones (75) 1984, 409 - 423) with an "Euler system" construction/argument (such as Kato's, as alluded to in David Loeffler's answer).

Comment: Yes. But to my knowledge, there is no suitable Euler system for the additive case.
Therefore, not much is yet known in the additive case, am I right?

Comment: Correct, at least as far as I know. The nonvanishing theorems are blind to the reduction type, but the Euler systems and p-adic L-functions constructions (which are typically only available for good ordinary, multiplicative, or special cases of good supersingular reduction) depend greatly upon it.

Comment: So here I stand - poor fool! - once more,
\\
no wiser than I was before.
\\
(Goethe)

Comment: Well … be bold, and mighty forces will come to your aid :)

Comment: I'm unsure what's meant by the assertion "there is no suitable Euler system for the additive case". Kato's Euler system construction works, and combined with Rohrlich's work it solves the problem over the cyclotomic tower, for all quotienst of modular Jacobians and and all primes $p$ -- it's completely blind to the reduction type, to borrow @jvo's phrase. The existence of the p-adic $L$-function is more restricted but it isn't relevant for this argument.  (I have no idea whether one needs more input from the cyclotomic theory to say anything over the larger Kummer tower, though.)

Comment: Sorry, my bad: I had forgotten how Kato works, and should have looked more carefully before posting ... The results of Darmon-Tian are all stated for good ordinary reduction, though it is not clear to me whether this is strictly necessary for their arguments. These results for Kummer towers are fragmentary in any case, though I imagine more could be done in this direction now.

Comment: @jvo: The reduction type is crucial to Darmon's and Tian's argument. Does anyone of you know how to acquire a (scanned) electronic copy of Kato's article? I am about 100 km away from the next library (vacationing at my parents'), and the Société Mathématique de France does not allow their subscribing libraries to publish Astérisque digitally.

Comment: @jdh: Thanks for checking this out! There is a copy here at the moment: http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~riccardo.brasca/pages/files/K2.pdf. I seem to recall that the deduction requires arguments from Kato's "Euler Systems, Iwasawa Theory, and Selmer Groups" too. Colmez and Scholl have also written expository accounts of this construction/argument: See Colmez, "La conjecture de Birch et Swinnerton-Dyer p-adique" and Scholl, "An introduction to Kato's Euler systems".

Comment: @jvo: I had found the digital version you mentioned earlier, but it lacks pages 147-165. These pages however contain Thm. 14.4.
It seems there is no choice for me but to travel the 100 kilometers.

Comment: @jdh: Too bad! I would offer you a full copy myself if I had one. (I am currently waiting to get full library access at my new university). Also,100 km is quite a trek (!) -- though perhaps only the beginning of it if you do go through Kato's entire argument …

Comment: @jdh The scanned typescript of Kato's article missing 20 pages, with "Prof. Greenberg" written on the cover in biro, seems to be all over the web; but I have a better one. Email me and I can send you a copy.